# Consul Helm installation error, no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to install the consul helm chart, version `10.12.6`  from bitnami link https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/consul. But when I run the `terraform apply` command it shows following errors

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "devt2-d1-***-consul-tls-init-cleanup" namespace: "devt2-d1" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

Following are the software version I used

**Kubernetes EKS Cluster version**

`1.23`

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24+", GitVersion:"v1.24.13-eks-0a21954", GitCommit:"6305d65c340554ad8b4d7a5f21391c9fa34932cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-15T00:37:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.17-eks-a5565ad", GitCommit:"23f44c7dd4e8e23856387345e7cb80bf0f93ced6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-06-15T21:19:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**helm version**

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.3", GitCommit:"323249351482b3bbfc9f5004f65d400aa70f9ae7", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.3"}
```

**terraform version**

```
Terraform v1.5.3
```

I looked into the file under consul,
`**consul/charts/common/templates/_capabilities.tpl**`
and I find below code

```
{{/*
Return the appropriate apiVersion for RBAC resources.
*/}}
{{- define "common.capabilities.rbac.apiVersion" -}}
{{- if semverCompare "<1.17-0" (include "common.capabilities.kubeVersion" .) -}}
{{- print "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- print "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

It looks like the `semverCompare` comparison fails and thus it add `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` version. As, I am using the Kubernetes `1.23` version, thus it should take the `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`.

Can you please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: The tpl file is created by you? Is that the entire file?

Comment: You are actually trying to install the AKS version for EKS, which you probably should not. Also, this is a non-official Helm chart. You should maybe try with this one: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/consul.

Comment: Sorry @MarkoE I have updated the question. I have used the link which you have mentioned. But still I am getting the same issue. I have downloaded the consul tgz file, **consul-10.12.6.tgz** and extracted it. From there I find this tpl file.

Comment: Ok, so you could temporarily use `kubeVersion: "1.23"` in the values.yaml file.

Comment: I have used the same, but still the same error occurs. @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue.
 As suggested in comment I used `kubeVersion` in `values.yaml` file but instead of setting value to `1.23` I set it to `1.23-0` and then its working fine.